# `latexmk` with cleanup and `-pvc`

Tags: latexmk

I am unable to put the `-pvc` (preview continuously) and `-c` (clean up) options together for `latexmk`.

```
latexmk -pdf -pvc -c file.tex
```

My observation: After giving `-c` option, the file gets compiled, (regeneratable) files are deleted and I am back to the command prompt.

Is it possible to achieve this?

-- Mike

Comment: I'm not quite understanding.  `-pvc` implies continuous compilation, which needs the auxiliary files, which means they can't be deleted.  Or are you wanting the auxiliary files to be regenerated whenever you make a change?  Why not just leave them around?

Comment: @Teepeemm This is precisely I want! I would like to regenerate all auxiliary files every time src file.tex is updated. and get deleted upon successful compilation. I need this as I have some restrictions on bandwidth and filesystem in terms of number of files. (Weird, huh?)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR is: Those options cannot work together. Below is why, after some research.

The `latexmk` man page documentation has the following:

```
In its new version, latexmk has a highly
general and efficient solution, ... and a
symptom is that latexmk generates an extra
file (with extension .fdb_latexmk, by default)
that contains the source file information.
```

Now regarding the `-c` option:

```
Clean up (remove) all regeneratable files
generated by latex and bibtex or biber except
dvi, postscript and pdf. These files are a
combination of log files, aux files, latexmk's
database file of source file information, and
those with extensions specified in the
@generated_exts configuration variable. In
addition, files specified by the $clean_ext
configuration variable are removed.
```

When I ran `latexmk -pdf -pvc -c file`, after having generated a clean and make via `latexmk -pdf -pvc -gg file`, the `-c` option caused all the generated files, *including file.fdb_latexmk*, to be deleted, save `file.pdf` and the original `file.tex'.

Now, here's the rub: `file.fdb_latexmk` contains a fair bit of info on what files were generated, what packages were loaded, and so on, as well as hashes of the files, including the source. One cannot simply `touch file.tex` and trigger a remake (as one might do with `make`). One must alter the file so that the hash changes. So if you delete the file with the hashes on all the generated files, then `latexmk` will enter a state in which it is "done" and it either halts on control-c or returns to the shell prompt.

In short, one cannot delete the file information database and the other generated files, expecting `latexmk` to work with similar jiggery-pokery as GNU make might. The shell script by @user5325 has a very different expectation of what "being modified" means than `latexmk`, as `touch file.tex` will trigger it, making it run `latexmk`, which then will not always work properly (if at all) and generate undocumented behavior like waiting on conditions that will never happen and necessitating a control-c.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small shell script:

```
f=/tmp/$$.tmp
touch $f
src=foo.tex
src="$1";
echo -e "$src -- $f\n";

while true
do
    if [ ${src} -nt ${f} ];
    then
        echo "File modified";
        latexmk -c ${src}
        sleep 5;
    fi;
    touch ${f};
    sleep 5;    # This is essential.
done
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: If one has to use bash script, why use `latexmk` in that case? Just put `pdflatex`, followed by `rm -f` commands... I believe this can be achieved with the power of `latexmk`.

Comment: I may be overlooking things, but I'm not seeing how you accomplish the `-pvc` portion.

Comment: @MikeV.D.C. `latexmk` can do much more than just a single rub of `pdflatex` - e.g. it will repeatedly compile the document until all the cross references, tables of contents, indexes, etc, are self-consistent, but only do the *minimum* number of recompiles to reach that state. (That's why it seems pointless to me to delete all the auxiliary files *every* time you run `latexmk` - it is just making `latexmk` work harder for no obvious reason).

Comment: @Teepeemm, I suspect that @user5325 is using some *nix system (e.g. ubuntu). So the default previewer (e.g. evince on ubuntu), once opened, automatically update the document on every change. Thus achieving `-pvc`.

Comment: @alephzero, second line in my comment above, precisely meant that `latexmk` is much more powerful. I just explained the reason behind my (weird) requirement (comment below the original post).